# How to hide script from process list in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell-script, process-management, w

I have a script in linux:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:1
value=$(</home/pace/Desktop/BODVersion.txt)
cd $value
gnome-terminal \
        --tab -t "CTCLManager" -e " sh -c 'sleep 1s; ./startapp CTCLManager' "\
        --tab -t "SMM" -e " sh -c 'sleep 10s; ./startapp SMM' "\
        --tab -t "ClientCommunicator" -e " sh -c 'sleep 20s; ./startapp ClientCommunicator' "\
        --tab -t "GATS" -e " sh -c 'sleep 30s; ./startapp GATS' "\
```

My problem is that once I run this script on my server (GUI) and issue the `w` command on the same server from the CLI then I got the following output:

```
[root@demo ~]# w
 12:23:27 up  8:22, 10 users,  load average: 4.12, 2.92, 1.75
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    192.168.0.100   11:43    0.00s  0.00s  0.00s w
pace     pts/1    :1               12:16    6:39   2.38s  0.00s sh -c sleep 1s; ./startapp CTCLManager
pace     pts/2    :1               12:16    6:39   0.05s  0.00s sh -c sleep 10s; ./startapp SMM
pace     pts/3    :1               12:16    6:39   0.20s  0.00s sh -c sleep 20s; ./startapp ClientCommunicator
pace     pts/5    :1               12:16    6:39  12:52   0.00s sh -c sleep 30s; ./startapp GATS
[root@demo ~]#
```

I don't want to display this from `w`, please help me to hide my script in the output from `w`.

Answer (score 1):

Lets consider a simple script for example:

```
[09:37] [vhost0 ~] # cat script.sh
echo "sleeping..."; sleep 100.
```

I run it, chec second terminal and here is what I see:

```
[09:37] [vhost0 ~] # w
 09:36:42 up 17:20,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.03, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    192.168.56.1     Wed20    2.00s  0.07s  0.00s sleep 100
root     pts/1    192.168.56.1     09:08    0.00s  0.09s  0.01s w
```

But then we modify the script:

```
[09:40] [vhost0 ~] # cat script.sh
secretcommand() { echo "sleeping..."; sleep 100; }

echo SECRET | secretcommand
```

Checking the `w`...

```
[09:36] [vhost0 ~] # w
 09:40:40 up 17:24,  3 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0    192.168.56.1     Wed20    8.00s  0.10s  0.00s bash script.sh
root     pts/1    192.168.56.1     09:08    0.00s  0.09s  0.00s w
```

Sure, its not like we're completely hide your presence from view, but still, that's hiding your dirty secrets from your parents ;)

#### UPD

Here is how the updated script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:1
value=$(</home/pace/Desktop/BODVersion.txt)
cd $value
secretcommand() {
        gnome-terminal \
                --tab -t "CTCLManager" -e " sh -c 'sleep 1s; ./startapp CTCLManager' "\
                --tab -t "SMM" -e " sh -c 'sleep 10s; ./startapp SMM' "\
                --tab -t "ClientCommunicator" -e " sh -c 'sleep 20s; ./startapp ClientCommunicator' "\
                --tab -t "GATS" -e " sh -c 'sleep 30s; ./startapp GATS' "\;
}

echo SECRET | secretcommand
```

Comment: I am using this script but unable to run script

[root@D ~]# cat co.sh
#!/bin/bash
export DISPLAY=:1
value=$(</root/path.txt)
cd $value
gnome-terminal \
        secretcommand() { --tab -t "CTCLManager" -e " sh -c 'sleep 1s; ./startapp CTCLManager' "\; }
        secretcommand() { --tab -t "SMM" -e " sh -c 'sleep 10s; ./startapp SMM' "\; }
[root@D ~]#

Output:
[root@D ~]$ co.sh
/root/co.sh: -c: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/root/co.sh: -c: line 5: `        secretcommand() { --tab -t "CTCLManager" -e " sh -c 'sleep 1s; ./startapp CTCLManager' "\; }'
[root@D ~]$

Comment: Because you did it wrong. First: you made a function out of parameters rather that from full command. Second, you did not actually invoke the function anyway. And lastly, you did not do the trick with `echo` - without it the `w` will still show your command. I updated my answer for you.